# How to compare two json and store mismatch into third json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, excel, sharepoint

I'm new to React and Sharepoint, I want to compare two Json data's and store the mismatch from second Json to third json. Here structure of second Json is different from first json.I've imported Sharepoint data as Json and Excel data as Json.

First Json
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyct4.jpg

Second Json
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EZWa.jpg

```
        public handelFile = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];

    const data = await file.arrayBuffer();
    const workbook = XLSX.read(data);

    const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
    const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
    console.log(jsonData);
  }

  public async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchData();
  }

  public async fetchData() {
    console.log(this.props.webURL);
    const items = await sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle("Aadhar_Data")
      .items.select("*", "Name/Title")
      .expand("Name")
      .get();

    console.log(items);
    this.setState({ Items: items });
    let html = await this.getHTML(items);
    this.setState({ HTML: html });
  }

  public findData = (id): void => {
    var itemID = id;
    var allitems = this.state.Items;
    var allitemsLength = allitems.length;
    if (allitemsLength > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < allitemsLength; i++) {
        if (itemID == allitems[i].Id) {
          this.setState({
            ID: itemID,
            Name: allitems[i].Name.Title,
            NameId: allitems[i].NameId,
            AadharNumber: allitems[i].Aadhar_x0020_Nuber,
            Age: allitems[i].Age,
            Gender: allitems[i].Gender,
            Phone: allitems[i].Phone,
            FatherName: allitems[i].Father_x0020_Name,
            EmailId: allitems[i].EmailId,
            City: allitems[i].City,
            State: allitems[i].State,
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public async getHTML(items) {
    var tabledata = (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Aadhar Number</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Father Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {items &&
            items.map((item, i) => {
              return [
                <tr key={i} onClick={() => this.findData(item.ID)}>
                  <td>{item.Name.Title}</td>
                  <td>{item.Aadhar_x0020_Nuber}</td>
                  <td>{item.Age}</td>
                  <td>{item.Gender}</td>
                  <td>{item.Phone}</td>
                  <td>{item.Father_x0020_Name}</td>
                  <td>{item.Email}</td>
                  <td>{item.City}</td>
                  <td>{item.State}</td>
                </tr>,
              ];
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
    return await tabledata;
  }
```